# Creating and transitioning views without using storyboard with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a new `UIViewController` class in a new file and transition to that `UIViewController` from the default `ViewController`. In `Objective-C` I would create a new file along with it's corresponding xib file then import that file into my main `ViewController.m` and use the view's `presentViewController` method to transition to the new view.

Example: from main `ViewController.m`

```
SecondViewController* secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewControllerXib" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:secondView animated:YES completion:nil];
secondView = nil;
```

Then return to main `ViewController.m` using

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have search around but all the examples I've come across are all using `Storyboard` which I prefer not to use. How can I achieve this without the using `Storyboard` in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing different in terms of using Storyboards and .XIB files or doing all UIKit in pure code. Swift and Obj-C have access to the same IDE tools in this regard so you might be looking for a problem that isn't there.

Seems like you're just asking how to write Swift syntax based on existing Obj-C code. "Programmatic View Controller Examples with Swift" ought to be googlable with a little more effort, but to your code:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    func foo() {
        let secondView = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewControllerXib", bundle: nil)
        presentViewController(secondView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func bar() {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was overthinking it and confused myself.